# Search pipe filter não atualiza alterações no meu template

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

Eu possuo o seguinte search pipe filter:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
    if (!items) {
        return [];
    }
    if (!field || !value) {
        return items;
    }

    return items.filter(singleItem =>
        singleItem[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    )}
}
```

**Input:**

```
<input placeholder="Nome do produto" [(ngModel)]="anunciosFiltro.name" type="text" name="filtra" id="filtra">
```

E então tenho a tabela com os dados a ser filtrados:

```
 <table>
  <tr *ngFor="let anuncio of tabelaAnuncioContas.Anuncio.products | search: 'name' : anunciosFiltro.name; let i = index">

                        <td>

                          <svg class="componenteTabelaResponsivo" matTooltip="Anúncio ativo" *ngIf="anuncio.status == 'enabled' && anuncio.associations[0].status == 'linked'" style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path fill="rgb(161,196,66)" d="M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2Z" />
                          </svg>

                        </td>

  </tr>
```

Está filtrando normalmente, mas há um momento que os dados da minha tabela são alterados, e se o pipe filter estiver filtrado algo, os dados da tabela filtrado não recebe as alterações realizadas na função, eu tentei:

```
alteraDadoTabela(){   
 this.sortedData.Contas[this.indexContaAlterada].Anuncio.products[this.indexAnuncioAlterado].status = status;
}
```

A alteração no template é realizada só quando não é utilizado o pipe filter.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver as alterações no template usando o **pure:false**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'search',
  pure: false,
})
```

https://angular.io/guide/pipes